OTEL Configuration for Datadog-Agent
I'm trying to set up OpenTelemetry to collect data from the Tyk API Gateway and send it to Datadog. I started with this description: Tyk OpenTelemetry with Datadog. Based on the description, the configuration file for OTEL shall look like this:
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317
processors:
  batch:
    send_batch_max_size: 100
    send_batch_size: 10
    timeout: 10s
exporters:
  datadog:
    api:
      site: "YOUR-DATADOG-SITE"
      key: "YOUR-DATAGOG-API-KEY"
service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [datadog]

My problem is that I cannot connect directly to Datadog using the site and key attributes. Instead, I need to use the Datadog Agent, which is accessible in my K8s environment via hostname:port.
My question is: Is the Datadog Exporter capable of sending data to the Datadog Agent, rather than directly to Datadog?
Can you please help me?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I clarified the question as requested.
